# Injecting different implementations in console/web in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony4

I have an interface `UserIdProvider` that has two implementations:

```
ConsoleUserIdProvider - it takes user id from CLI input option
RequestUserIdProvider - it comes from {userId} parameter in route
```

How should I configure `Kernel` to inject console implementation when I run CLI only, and how to use second one when it is regular request to web server?

I created separate `ConsoleKernel extends Kernel` for `console.php` where I load:

```
$loader->load($confDir . '/console_services.yml');
```

But unfortunately it overrides via cache in `APP_ENV=prod` mode regular `Kernel` where `RequestUserIdProvider` is supposed to be used.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I should create new `cli` environment for that purpose.

1. I removed `ConsoleKernel` that loads custom yml file. It's not necessary.
2. I renamed `console_services.yml` to follow Symfony practice, which is supposed to be: `services_cli.yml` in my case. My console specific implementation is placed there.
3. I also changed `console.php` to disable debug mode in `cli` environment like for `prod`:

```
$notLikeProdEnv = !in_array($env, ["prod", "cli"], true);
$debug = ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] ?? $notLikeProdEnv) && !$input->hasParameterOption(['--no-debug', '']);
```

4. Thanks to that when I run `php console --env=cli` I can see only commands specific to `cli` environment and also my `ConsoleUserIdProvider` implementation.